Unclear behaviour of variable signatures in alloy models
I'm currently learning Alloy, and I'm struggling to understand the behaviour of variable signatures. I'm attempting to model a straightforward rental system where all items are initially available and can be rented out to customers.
var one sig Customer {
    var rented: set RentedItems,
}


var abstract sig Item {
}

var sig AvailableItem in Item {}
var sig RentedItems in Item {}

fact init {
    no RentedItems
    all v:Item | v in AvailableItem
    //#Item = 3
}


pred rent [v: AvailableItem, c:Customer] { 
    c.rented' = c.rented + v
    AvailableItem' = AvailableItem - v
}

pred NoMoreItems {
    no AvailableItem
}

fact trans { 
    always (NoMoreItems or (some v:AvailableItem, c:Customer | rent[v, c]))
}

run {} for 3

First, I'm unsure if this approach is the right way to implement this spec because I struggled to model it using static signatures
Secondly, during execution, I noticed instances where items seem to appear or disappear unexpectedly between states. My understanding was that variable signature atoms could change through predicates, adding or removing them as needed, but they shouldn't simply materialize out of nowhere. Is there a method to enforce a fixed number of atoms for the Item signature other than setting the value in a fact?

I expected the atoms of Item to stay consistent throughout the execution but and items to change from available to rented.

The semantics of Alloy is based upon logic: the value of a signature or relation is only influenced by constraints you wrote, so what's not forbidden to happen may happen. This is in contrast with languages meant to be executed (state machines, programs...) where the only possible changes are those explicitly stated.
Mutable (= var) signatures or relations are not forced to remain constant along a trace, so there are instances where they change and some where they don't. Static (= non-var) signatures and relations have the additional constraint of remaining constant along every execution.
If you want to allow mutations in a trace, but only when some events (modeled as preds) happen, then you must not only describe what changes when events happen (which you did) but also what does not change. This is called frame conditions.
